# How do I get older IBM Java Runtimes?

Tags: java, download, runtime, ibm-server

I need all(!) IBM SDKs for Java 8 for testing purposes.

I tried to find some kind of a legacy download but as far as I know IBM itself doesnt offer that.

Am wrong with my assumption or is there any other repositry for those files ?

Comment: Do you understand you are talking dozens of executables?  Is there a reason you are worried about compatibility with an insecure version of the SDK?  There is a reason updates were released.

Comment: Yeah, I looked around for you and found nothing, they did use to have licensing restrictions so maybe thats related in some way

Comment: Its mostly a "just-in-case" scenario where we want to be prepared if a customer says "hey your software doesnt work" and its some kind of runtime-based problem.

But its quite a shame that neither you nor me could find any source for the previous versions.

Thank you for trying!